# Residue Calculus: Compute $\int_{\gamma(0,1)} \frac{e^{az}}{(a+z)^2}dz$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

hi there i'm just doing some exam prep and i've hit a snag here so i fear a fundamental misunderstanding on my part. i'll go through the entire question.

we consider the integral $\int_{\gamma(0,1)} \frac{e^{az}}{(a+z)^2}dz$ on A = $\mathbb{C} $\ {-a} and so f is entire on A (calculated via a previous part of the question). now we compute the integral for $|a| \neq 1$

Answer:
Let $|a|>1$ then the pole lies outside of $\gamma(0,1)$ and so

$$\int_{\gamma(0,1)}f(z) dz = 0$$ 
via the cauchy-goursat.

for $|a|<1$ the pole is inside of $\gamma(0,1)$ and of order 2

> this is where i believe im messing up

to calculate we use cauchy's residue theorem and so

$$\int_{\gamma(0,1)}f(z) dz =  2 \pi i ~res \{f,-a \}$$ 
(note i know that the actual theorem says we sum the residues but we only have a single residue)

Further for a function g with a pole of order m at a then
$$res\{g,a \} = \lim_{z \longrightarrow a} \frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}(z-a)^mg(z) $$

so tying this back into the actual question this gives

$$\int_{\gamma(0,1)}f(z) dz =  2 \pi i \lim_{z \longrightarrow -a} \frac{1}{(2-1)!}\frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}(z-a)^mf(z)$$
$$= 2\pi i \left[ \frac{d}{dz}\left((z-a)^2 \cdot \frac{e^{az}}{(z+a)^2}\right)\Bigg\rvert_{z = -a} ~ \right]$$

which i admit when i calculated turnt into something slightly complicated (which is why i believe ive made a mistake and have a misunderstanding) according to the answer sheet

$$res \{f,-a \} = ae^{-a^2}$$

giving the final answer as

$$\int_{\gamma(0,1)}f(z) dz = 2 \pi i ae^{-a^2}$$

any help would be great, in particular i think ive differentiated this wrong or i'm missing a rule

$$\frac{d}{dz} \left[\frac{(z-a)^2e^{az}}{(z+a)^2}\right] \Bigg\rvert_{z=-a} = \frac{a(z-a)(z^2 -a^2 + 4)e^{az}}{(z+a)^3}\Bigg\rvert_{z=-a} = \frac{a(-a-a)((-a)^2 -a^2 + 4)e^{a(-a)}}{(-a+a)^3}=\frac{(-2a^2)4e^{-a^2}}{(-a+a)^3}$$ 
which is nonsense....

any help would be great! thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You multiplied by $(z-a)^2$ when you should be multiplying by $(z+a)^2$ because the pole is at $z=-a$.

Comment: First. thank you for that. i didnt notice that,

now i'm just going to go crawl into a hole and cry...